# How to get a shape of a searched map in tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I am using

```
library(tmap)
qtm("London")
```

to get a map of London but can't find a way to get it in a shape?

```
tm_shape
```

Otherwise, I can only have it in view mode, not in plot mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You have to do it another way to get a map layer in `tmap_mode("plot")`.

In `tmap_mode("view")` you can just do it like that:

```
tm_shape(lnd) + tm_polygons(alpha = 0.7, col = "Pop_2001", legend.show = FALSE) + 
  tm_basemap(server = c('OpenStreetMap'))
```

With `tm_basemap(server = c('OpenStreetMap'))` not being necessary, but I've put it anyway, because here you can change the basemap, for example to `stamen`.

For `tmap_mode("plot")` you have to download the tiles manually. There are several ways to do that.

**1.** The `tmaptools`-package offers a function to do that `read_osm()`. To get the Tiles you do `lonmap <- bb("London") %>% read_osm(type = "osm")`, which returns a raster object.

**2.** Another alternative is `openmap()` from the `OpenStreetMap`-package, which would look like that:

```
london <- bb("London")
lonmap <- openmap(upperLeft = london[3:4], 
                  lowerRight = london[1:2], 
                  type = "osm",
                  mergeTiles = TRUE)
```

**3.** And of course there is `get_map()` from the `ggmap`-package for which you now need an API-key. This can't be put directly into `tm_shape()` however.

But to be honest `read_osm()` and `openmap()` both give me the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException

and I haven't been able to find a solution to it.

**4.** So I use even another one: The `getTiles()` function from the `cartography`-package. `getTiles` only takes `sf` or `sp` objects and returns a `RasterBrick`-object

```
library(tmap)
library(cartography)

lonmap <- getTiles(x = lnd, type = "osm")

tmap_mode("plot")

tm_shape(lonmap) + tm_rgb() + tm_shape(lnd) + 
  tm_polygons(alpha = 0.5,col = "Pop_2001", legend.show = FALSE)
```

Which gives you this:

[image: London Map]

A workaround for being able to use a bounding box would be:

```
lonmap <-  bb("London") %>% 
            matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>%
                SpatialPoints(proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")) %>%
                    getTiles(type = "osm")
```

The `lnd`, is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. Never mind the content. You can get it from here: 
https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/blob/master/data/london_sport.shp